# R software implementation of combining mixed treatment comparisons and meta-regression

Tags: r, meta-analysis, meta-regression, network-meta-analysis

I am currently conducting a meta-analysis in which I need to use a mixed treatment comparison method.  As I understand it, this method works in the following way:

Say you have a group of studies that make the following set of treatment comparisons:

- Intervention 1
- Intervention 2
- Intervention 3
- Control

You are interested in all possible comparisons between these treatments.  So, not only are you interested in intervention 1 versus control, intervention 2 versus control, and intervention 3 versus control, but also intervention 1 versus intervention 2, intervention 1 versus intervention 3, etc.  The problem occurs in that not all of the studies in your meta analysis include each intervention type.  So, while study 1 may have tested intervention 1, intervention 2, and a control group, study 2 tested intervention 2 and intervention 3 versus a control group.  And so on.  Mixed treatment comparisons ([Caldwell, Ades, & Higgins, 2005](http://www.bmj.com/content/331/7521/897?view=long&pmid=16223826); [Lu & Ades, 2004](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15449338); [Mills et al., 2011](http://www.dovepress.com/multiple-treatment-comparison-meta-analyses-a-step-forward-into-comple-peer-reviewed-article-CLEP)) arose as a way of using the indirect information from your sample of studies to estimate the magnitude of the missing comparisons.

For my study, I am interested in how several different moderators affect the magnitude of the various treatment comparisons.  I stumbled across a paper ([Nixon, Bansback, & Brennan, 2007](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16900557)) that combines the mixed treatment comparison method with meta-regression.  My problem is finding a good software implementation for this method (preferably an implementation in R, since I'm most familiar with R).  As far as I can tell, the [metafor](http://www.metafor-project.org/) package isn't able to handle mixed treatment comparisons.  Does anybody know whether there's a package out there that's able to handle both mixed treatment comparisons and meta-regression?

Comment: Please let me know, if you're you still interested in this topic - I wanted to share some information, but just paid attention to the dates...

Comment: I am!  I was editing the text of my old questions, and I discovered that doing these edits places the questions on the active list.  However, this is definitely still a topic I'm interested in if you have some extra information.

Comment: All right then - will post my answer soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot help you with an R implementation of the Nixon et al. paper. However, I remember a talk given by Ian White and colleagues on "Consistency and Inconsistency in Multiple Treatments Meta-Analysis: Models and Estimation". In this talk they presented a "multivariate random-effects meta-regression" which hopefully can be estimated using the [mvmeta](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mvmeta/mvmeta.pdf) package. There also seems a paper available (haven't checked it yet): "[Consistency and inconsistency in network meta-analysis: model estimation using multivariate meta-regression](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jrsm.1045/pdf)".

Comment: Bernd, thanks for your response.  It looks like the mvmeta package is very new (published on CRAN on August 24!).  The paper link references a Stata version of mvmeta, which seems to incorporate methods of dealing with mixed treatment comparisons.  I'll have to see whether that functionality was also ported over to the R version of the package.

Comment: It does indeed look like mvmeta has the appropriate functions for network meta-analysis (i.e., mixed treatment comparisons).  Additionally, I have discovered several resources that might be useful for analysts wishing to use this method: the [NICE Decision Support Unit website](http://www.nicedsu.org.uk/Evidence-Synthesis-TSD-series%282391675%29.htm) and the [Multiple Treatments Meta-analysis](http://www.mtm.uoi.gr/#) website.